# Unable to follow the road path mapped on google maps on react native expo

Tags: python, reactjs, react-native, google-maps, expo

**I am developing an app for public transport in my city.**

A public transport vehicle follows certain routes and travels through certain stops for each route. To create such a route in code, I've made a sample dataset in which I've defined a route details such as route name, route description etc.. and also added stops for each route. And for each stop I've manually added stopname, stopId, latitude and longitude for each stop (I manually picked up the coordinates from google maps for each stop).

Now, I want to generate a path/route for the user to travel onto (user will provide start stopId and end stopId). For generating a route, I've made an algorithm on python as a backend which takes these start stop and end stop Ids and then generates a path based on my sample dataset which I've mentioned above. For example if user enters start stopId as 101, and end stopId as 104, it generates the route between these stops. Now, I've used google maps directions API in my algorithm and it was generating a path according to google maps, but when using this provided route in my front end to map onto google maps, the path/route wasn't following the road. It was just making straight lines to the coordinates provided by the algorithm (which supposedly are stops' coordinates).

Now to fix this, we encountered Road API for google maps. But after integrating the road API into our route calculation algorithm, the path is still not following the road. The problem which we are facing right now is that shortest route path (generated by our algo) is not following the road.

I don't know if there is something wrong with the dataset, our algo or just my approach to this project.

**Here is the algorithm's calculated route data:**

```
    [{'start_location': {'latitude': 33.51180437744356, 'longitude': 73.17893349284849}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.538766, 'lng': 73.1803894}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.538766, 'lng': 73.1803894}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5427329, 'lng': 73.1780272}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5427329, 'lng': 73.1780272}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5519203, 'lng': 73.17120179999999}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5519203, 'lng': 73.17120179999999}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5629983, 'lng': 73.1629016}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5629983, 'lng': 73.1629016}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5695451, 'lng': 73.15800920000001}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5695451, 'lng': 73.15800920000001}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5760878, 'lng': 73.15312899999999}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5760878, 'lng': 73.15312899999999}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5775459, 'lng': 
73.1520986}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5775459, 'lng': 73.1520986}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5862209, 'lng': 73.1455458}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5862209, 'lng': 73.1455458}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5964098, 'lng': 73.1379766}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5964098, 'lng': 73.1379766}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.6033826, 'lng': 73.1327283}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.6033826, 'lng': 73.1327283}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.6035184, 'lng': 73.13262879999999}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.6035184, 'lng': 73.13262879999999}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.601471, 'lng': 73.1261758}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.601471, 'lng': 73.1261758}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.60735140000001, 'lng': 73.1131072}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.60735140000001, 'lng': 73.1131072}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.6045784, 'lng': 73.0988345}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.6045784, 'lng': 73.0988345}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5998616, 'lng': 73.0861807}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5998616, 'lng': 73.0861807}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5991272, 'lng': 73.0802733}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5991272, 'lng': 73.0802733}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5983399, 'lng': 73.0797066}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5983399, 'lng': 73.0797066}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5943413, 'lng': 73.0790335}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5943413, 'lng': 73.0790335}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5921905, 'lng': 73.07961519999999}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5921905, 'lng': 73.07961519999999}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5915565, 'lng': 73.0802326}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5915565, 'lng': 73.0802326}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5908881, 'lng': 73.079771}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5908881, 'lng': 73.079771}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5881734, 'lng': 73.0755504}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5881734, 'lng': 73.0755504}, 'end_location': {'lat': 33.5848764, 'lng': 73.0660943}}, {'start_location': {'lat': 33.5848764, 'lng': 73.0660943}, 'end_location': {'latitude': 33.587303399999996, 'longitude': 73.07452959999999}}]
```

**This is my algorithm file:**

```
import googlemaps
import networkx as nx
import requests
class RouteCalculationEngine:
    def __init__(self, data, google_maps_api_key):
        self.graph = nx.Graph()
        self.data = data
        self.gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=google_maps_api_key)
        self._prepare_graph()
        
        # Initialize the Google Maps client

    def _prepare_graph(self):
        for route in self.data:
            previous_stop = None
            for stop in route['stops']:
                self.graph.add_node(stop['stopId'], latitude=stop['latitude'], longitude=stop['longitude'])

                if previous_stop:
                    distance = self._get_distance(previous_stop, stop)
                    self.graph.add_edge(previous_stop['stopId'], stop['stopId'], weight=distance)  # using actual distance
                previous_stop = stop


    def calculate_route(self, start_stop_id, end_stop_id):
        # Validate if the stops exist
        if not self.graph.has_node(start_stop_id) or not self.graph.has_node(end_stop_id):
            print(f"One or both of the stops {start_stop_id} and {end_stop_id} do not exist.")
            return

        # Find the shortest path between two stops
        try:
            shortest_path = nx.shortest_path(self.graph, source=start_stop_id, target=end_stop_id, weight='weight')
            
            # Detailed path including names and coordinates
            detailed_path = self._process_path(shortest_path) # ADD BACK THE DISTANCE AND TIME IF NECESSARY

            return {
                'path': detailed_path,  # This is the detailed path from the previous step
                # 'total_distance': total_distance,
                # 'estimated_time': estimated_time  # This could be in minutes or hours, depending on preference
            }

            # return detailed_path
        except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
            print(f"No path between {start_stop_id} and {end_stop_id}.")
            return

    def _get_stop_name_by_id(self, stop_id):
        // Implementation...


    def _get_segment(self, start_stop_id, end_stop_id):
        forward_segment = None
        reverse_segment = None
        // Rest of the implementation...
        

    def _process_path(self, path):
        detailed_path = []
        total_distance = 0.0  # in meters
        total_duration = 0.0  # in seconds

        # Prepare the coordinates for the Google Maps and Roads API query.
        coordinates = []
        for stop_id in path:
            stop = self.graph.nodes[stop_id]
            coordinates.append(f"{stop['latitude']},{stop['longitude']}")

        # Convert the list of coordinates to a string to pass to the Roads API
        path_points = "|".join(coordinates)


        #query Google Maps for the route. We use the first and last points as start and end,
        # and all intermediate points as waypoints.
        directions = self.gmaps.directions(
            origin=coordinates[0],
            destination=coordinates[-1],
            waypoints=coordinates[1:-1],
            mode="driving",  # You can change the mode here
            optimize_waypoints=True
        )

        if not directions:
            raise Exception("Google Maps could not find a route.")

        # Google Maps returns a lot of data, but we are interested in the total distance and duration,
        # and the route's step-by-step instructions.
        route_legs = directions[0]['legs']
        for leg in route_legs:
            leg_distance = leg['distance']['value']  # distance is in meters
            leg_duration = leg['duration']['value']  # duration is in seconds

            total_distance += leg_distance
            total_duration += leg_duration

            # For a detailed path, we could also extract each step in the leg.
            for step in leg['steps']:
                detailed_path.append({
                    # 'distance': step['distance'],
                    # 'duration': step['duration'],
                    'start_location': step['start_location'],
                    'end_location': step['end_location'],
                    # 'instructions': step['html_instructions']
                })

        total_distance /= 1000  # converting to kilometers
        total_duration /= 60  # converting to minutes

        roads_api_response = requests.get(
            f"https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path={path_points}&interpolate=true&key={self.gmaps.key}"
        )
        snapped_points = roads_api_response.json().get('snappedPoints', [])

        if not snapped_points:
            raise Exception("Google Roads API could not snap the path.")

        # We will create a new list of 'snapped' segments based on the Roads API response
        snapped_path = []

        for point in snapped_points:
            location = point.get('location')
            snapped_path.append({
                'latitude': location['latitude'],
                'longitude': location['longitude']
            })

        if snapped_path:
            # Ensure we have at least one entry in the detailed_path to update
            if detailed_path:
                # Update the start_location of the first step and end_location of the last step
                detailed_path[0]['start_location'] = snapped_path[0]
                detailed_path[-1]['end_location'] = snapped_path[-1]
        print(detailed_path)
        return detailed_path # ADD THE DISTANCE AND TIME BACK AGAIN IF NECESSARY
```

**Flask API File to communicate with front end:**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from RouteCalculationEngine import RouteCalculationEngine  # Import your route calculation class
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
# Load your routes data
google_maps_api_key = 'API_KEY'

# Define this function to load your data
engine = RouteCalculationEngine(routes_data, google_maps_api_key)

@app.route('/calculate_route', methods=['POST'])
def calculate_route():
    data = request.json
    start_stop_id = data.get('start_stop_id')
    end_stop_id = data.get('end_stop_id')

    if not start_stop_id or not end_stop_id:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Missing parameters'}), 400
    else:
        print("Start Stop ID and End Stop ID recieved successfuly from front end!")
        print(start_stop_id)
        print(end_stop_id)

    result = engine.calculate_route(start_stop_id, end_stop_id)
 
    # print(f"Path: {result['path']}")
    return (result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.18.14', port=8000,debug=True)
```

**This is my screen file of my expo project:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Button, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import MapView, { Polyline, Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import axios from "axios";

const MapScreen = () => {
  const [coords, setCoords] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const calculateRoute = async () => {
    try {
      const apiEndpoint = "http://192.168.18.14:8000/calculate_route";

      const response = await axios.post(apiEndpoint, {
        start_stop_id: 101,
        end_stop_id: 208,
      });

      const data = response.data;

      // console.log(data.path);
      if (!data.path) {
        throw new Error("No route data received");
      }
      // console.log("DATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA::::::::::::", data.path);

      const points = data.path.map((step) => ({
        latitude: step.start_location.lat,
        longitude: step.start_location.lng,
      }));

      console.log("Coordinates: ", coords);
      setCoords(points);
      setError("");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      setError("Error calculating route");
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 33.603821356886264,
          longitude: 73.13451651025709,
          latitudeDelta: 0.04,
          longitudeDelta: 0.04,
        }}
      >
        {coords && coords.length > 1 && (
          <Polyline coordinates={coords} strokeWidth={4} strokeColor="blue" />
        )}
        {coords && coords.length > 1 && (
          <>
            <Marker coordinate={coords[0]} title="Start" />
            <Marker coordinate={coords[coords.length - 1]} title="End" />
          </>
        )}
      </MapView>
      {error ? <Text>{error}</Text> : null}
      <Button title="Calculate Route" onPress={calculateRoute} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});

export default MapScreen;
```

Here are some screenshots of the path that is mapped onto the google maps:

[Not following path:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U90v2.jpg)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In addition to the community comment above, it would be good to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting help